# Using Spring Security to do operation on Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Is there a way to use Spring Security to connect with Facebook and then retrieve a token which will be used to do some operations on the Facebook Graph API (profile name, groups, etc ...) and then refresh that token as long as the user is using my app ?

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I found a detailed tutorial using this stack : Spring Security 5, Spring Boot 2.2 and ReactJS. I recommend it for everyone searching for the same subject : https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/